# Graphql React Dev Tools Missing field while writing result

Tags: graphql, apollo

I am running a graphql query to create a person object. The query works fine and the person is created. However I am receiving the following error in the console

```
react_devtools_backend.js:2842 Missing field 'create_person' while writing result {
  "__typename": "PersonResponse",
  "error": null,
  "person": {
    "__typename": "Person",
    "hire_date": "2020-10-01",
    "name": {
      "__typename": "Name",
      "first_name": "Joe",
      "last_name": "Doe",
      "middle_name": ""
    },
    "person_id": {
      "__typename": "PersonId",
      "id_": "44df8f7c-d019-410c-89b4-be602f631055"
    },
    "preferred_name": {
      "__typename": "PreferredName",
      "first_name": "J",
      "last_name": "Dee",
      "middle_name": null
    }
  },
  "status": 201
}
```

This error seems to be saying that my query is missing a field `create_person` however `create_person` is not a field it is the name of the query. My first thought was that the message is due to the null fields (even though they are not required).  I tried removing these fields from the schema and I still get the error. I am using React Dev Tools chrome extension but still not sure why I get this error.

As requested the gql schema:

```
const graphqlSchema = buildSchema(`
type Query {
  people(person_id: String): [Person]!
  emergency_contacts(
    person_id: String!
    emergency_contact_id: String
  ): [EmergencyContact]!
  person_success: PersonResponse!
  person_not_found: PersonResponse!
  person_deleted: PersonResponse!
  emergency_contact_success: EmergencyContactResponse!
}

scalar Datetime

type PersonId {
  id_: String!
}

type Name {
  first_name: String!
  last_name: String!
  middle_name: String
}

input NameInput {
  first_name: String!
  last_name: String!
  middle_name: String
}

input UpdateNameInput {
  first_name: String
  last_name: String
  middle_name: String
}

type ExemptStatus {
  code: String!
  description: String!
}

type PreferredName {
  first_name: String
  last_name: String
  middle_name: String
}

input PreferredNameInput {
  first_name: String
  last_name: String
  middle_name: String
}

type Relationship {
  code: String!
  display: String!
  description: String!
}

type Address {
  line_1: String!
  line_2: String!
  city: String!
  state: String!
  zip_code: String!
}

type Person {
  person_id: PersonId!
  name: Name!
  hire_date: Datetime!
  preferred_name: PreferredName
  contact_info: ContactInfo
  exempt_status: ExemptStatus
  hired_hours_per_week: Float
  hired_hours_per_two_weeks: Float
  emergency_contacts: [EmergencyContact]
}

type PersonResponse {
  status: Int
  error: String
  person: Person
}

input PersonInput {
  name: NameInput!
  hire_date: Datetime!
  preferred_name: PreferredNameInput
  contact_info: ContactInfoInput
  exempt_status_code: String
  hired_hours_per_week: Float
  hired_hours_per_two_weeks: Float
}

input AddressInput {
  line_1: String!
  line_2: String!
  city: String!
  state: String!
  zip_code: String!
}

type ContactInfo {
  primary_phone: String!
  alternate_phone: String
  email: String
  address: Address
}

input ContactInfoInput {
  primary_phone: String!
  alternate_phone: String
  email: String
  address: AddressInput
}

type EmergencyContactId {
  id_: String!
}

type EmergencyContact {
  emergency_contact_id: EmergencyContactId!
  name: Name!
  relationship: Relationship!
  contact_info: ContactInfo!
}

input EmergencyContactInput {
  name: NameInput!
  relationship_code: String!
  contact_info: ContactInfoInput!
}

input UpdateEmergencyContactInput {
  name: NameInput
  relationship_code: String
  contact_info: ContactInfoInput
}

type EmergencyContactResponse {
  status: Int
  error: String
  person_id: PersonId
  emergency_contact: EmergencyContact
}

type Mutation {
  create_person(person_input: PersonInput): PersonResponse
  update_name(person_id: String!, name_input: UpdateNameInput!): PersonResponse
  update_hire_date(person_id: String!, hire_date: Datetime!): PersonResponse

  update_preferred_name(
    person_id: String!
    preferred_name_input: UpdateNameInput!
  ): PersonResponse
  delete_person(person_id: String!): PersonResponse
}
`);
```

Comment: Maybe a quick snippet of your GraphQL schema would help.

Comment: Added the schema

Comment: Can you show the query in which `create_person` is called in the front, please ?

Comment: In addition, have you tried using camelCase for your mutations (or queries) instead of snake case?